# How to stop UIView animation in iOS < 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

Is there any way to stop animation in iOS 3 ?

I know about:

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
 [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

, but it works only in iOS 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
if([view.layer repondsToSelector:@selector(removeAllAnimations)]) //Check if the CALayer responds to removeAllAnimations method for iOS4+
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
else
    [view.layer addAnimation:nil forKey:@"TheKeyOfTheAnimation"]; // Change TheKeyOfTheAnimation with key you have added animation for, you can also use nil for the key...
```

**UPDATE:** According to the docs removeAllAnimations is available since iOS2.0
removeAllAnimations
Remove all animations attached to the receiver.

```
- (void)removeAllAnimations
Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
CALayer.h
```

Comment: Xcode do not see layer property till i add QuartzCore.framework, Would it work if i add QuartzCore.framework to library as optional and use it?

Comment: There is no reason to add it as optional, as it is supported since ios2.0, so there wouldn't be a device without it...